# How to modify the line of a breakpoint in gdb?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I set a breakpoint and set its conditions and some other commands. Now I realize that I should had set it a few lines ahead. How can I change the line of the breakpoint without deleting it and losing its settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I change the line of the breakpoint without deleting it and losing its settings?

You can't.

What you can do is use `save breakpoints /tmp/bp.txt` command to save current settings for all breakpoints, edit the `/tmp/bp.txt` file to update the line info (or anything else), and finally `delete` to remove current breakpoints and `source /tmp/bp.txt` to reload them.

Comment: Thank you! It is frustrating that such simple feature does not exist. May be I propose a patch to gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you will probably want to do that on many occasions, I suggest adding the following to your `.gdbinit`:

```
define loadbp
  delete breakpoints
  source .gdbbp
end
document loadbp
  Set stored breakpoints after deleting any current breakpoints.

The breakpoints to load (set) are expected in ./.gdbbp which is the file created by savebp, but can
be edited manually.

Some breakpoints may not be set because the needed shared object hasn't been loaded yet.  gdb
doesn't prompt when such breakpoint commands are not set interactively.  Consequently, it may be
necessary to run this command again, once the shared object has been loaded.  To account for cases
in which shared objects are loaded automatically by the dynamic loader, this command also sets a
breakpoint in main.  This ensures that there is an early opportunity to call this command again to
set shared object breakpoints.
end

define savebp
  save breakpoints .gdbbp
end
document savebp
  Store current breakpoints in .gdbbp for retrieval using loadbp.
end
```

To use those commands, you need to source `.gdbinit` or restart `gdb`. Then, type `savebp` and hit Enter at the `gdb` command prompt, edit `./.gdbbp` as desired, then type `loadbp` and hit Enter at the `gdb` command prompt.

Note that, as written, those commands save and load `.gdbbp` relative to the current directory. Usually, that's the directory from which you started `gdb`, but you can change it from within `gdb`, so pay attention to where the file is saved. (You can run the `pwd` command at the `gdb` command prompt to see what the current directory is.)